# How to get cookies value from client service to server service in react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

How to fetch cookies value from client service to server service in react js?
The cookie successfully stored on the clent side but when i am trying console from server side it is showing undefined .

please help me !!

index.js (server side):

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
const app = express();
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import connection from "./database/db.js";
import Router from "./routes/route.js";
import auth from "./middleware/auth.js";

const corsOptions = {
    origin: true, //included origin as true
    credentials: true, //included credentials as true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use('/', Router);
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`server is running successfully at ${PORT}`);
})

connection();
```

Auth.js (Authentication middleware(server side)):

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import post from '../schema/post-schema.js'
import profile from '../schema/profile-schema.js';

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

        const token = req.cookies['jwt'];
        console.log("The token is", token) //it shows undefined
        const verifyuser = jwt.verify(token, "mynameismohitkumarfromnationalinstituteoftechnologyagartala");
        const user = await profile.findOne({ _id: verifyuser._id });
        
        console.log(verifyuser);
        console.log(user);
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json(error);
    }
}

export default auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at cookie options if the cookie is `HttpOnly` then you cant read the cookie from the client-side.